# Sharepoint list item bug in text column, part of written values get erased

Tags: 2010, custom-list, bug, front-end, multiple-lines-of-text

My problem is this -

Environment - I have a Sharepoint (2010) and a Custom list. The list items have couple columns, but only one of them has weird bug that randomly happens to different users. This column is of type Multiple lines of text and the setting is so it has 6 lines and is Enchansed rich text (hyperlinks, pics etc).

Symptom is this - when a user opens a new list item dialogue and starts writing text to that cell, very often if person presses Enter to add a line, some of the rows written text might magically erase two first letters of some of the rows. Typically this data disappearing happens in the row where enter key was pressed, but I have only managed to simulate this issue couple times so can't be sure if there is a pattern. Weirdest part is this - this only happens one time and it's always 2 first letters of a random row. Also on what row this happens seems to be very random, but this could be also randomized by end users different paces and writing speeds.

My best guesses - some how some of the javascript components etc are still loading in the background and the connection is lost between the server for small second or the code that grabs and formats paragraphs is so small a time halted and out of sync for these two characters to disappear or the code grabbing input has a bug.

But you tell me - have any of you experienced this kind of data loss behaviour and is there a know solution or a bug to this matter?

Comment: Does the developer console reveal any errors when this happens? Does the user use the RETURN or the ENTER key?

Comment: 43 user permission related errors when opening the form but none happening at the time when the bug manifest and no errors that I can find relation to the happening. I haven't tried other options except using ENTER button, but one time I'm not sure if I pressed BACKSPACE or ENTER when this happened.

Comment: The rich text fields are very browser dependent. I would suggest testing different browsers and versions, and if using IE to try with compatibility mode on and off.

Comment: All users using IE, so yeah could be worth a shot..

Comment: @StevenMulkerrins Toggling compatibility mode won't do anything, IE runs all intranet sites in compatibilty mode. But I would definitely try other browsers.

Comment: I tried with Google Chrome, and was not able to simulate the same results.. It seems with this knowledge that it has something to do with IE.

Comment: One new note - one of the end users was able to confirm a behavior where not only 2 first letters was removed but a 5 characters of a numeric string (postal code, this column is used for giving a address information) from the start of a new row. So this behavior really makes me think this has to be something to do with something loading in the back ground. There must be a very narrow time window when this happens. And to point it out, the string literally disappears after it has been written and can be confirmed to be written to that cell/column so it's not that the input hasn't been accepted.